# How to link to correctly urlencode spotify search

Tags: spotify, urlencode

Something seem to have changed in how one links to a spotify search. The following code should work:

```
<a href="spotify:search:track:castle+on+the+hill+artist:ed+sheeran">spotify:search:track:castle on the hill artist:ed sheeran</a>
```

When Spotify opens it says No result found for "track:castle+on+the+hill+artist:ed+sheeran"

We have also tried percent encoding:

```
<a href="spotify:search:track:castle%20on%20the%20hill%20artist:ed%20sheeran">Castle on the hill Ed Sheeran</a>
```

But this also fails.

Any advice on how to properly link to a Spotify search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, solution posted here
https://pappmaskin.no/2017/02/linking-to-a-spotify-search-with-both-track-and-artist/

There is a new format for the url:

```
track:"castle on the hill" artist:"ed sheeran"
```

And you need to urlencode that part separately, to

```
track%3A%22castle%20on%20the%20hill%22%20artist%3A%22ed%20sheeran%22.
```

And add spotify:search:in front:
      spotify:search:track%3A%22castle%20on%20the%20hill%22%20artist%3A%22ed%20sheeran%22

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to quote the fields?
As with the Spotify web API If you do that then
That means an “exact search”.
track:”check your self”
May not find track named “check yo self”
Where
track:check yo self
Might (I’ve excluded space encodings)

Have you tried to just encode the “:”
After track and artist?
And of course the spaces?